# Service-Worker, "TypeError:Request failed at <anonymous>"

Tags: html, browser-cache, basic-authentication, service-worker, http-status-code-401

I hope you can help me with my problem.
Currently I build a PWA with a service-worker. It registerd successful, but something is wrong with the installation.

The "caches.open"-promise result in an error: "TypeError: Request failed at ". You can see in Chrome, that the cache is registerd, but empty.
I already checked the cache urls thousand times..

Here is my Service-worker Code

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'surv-cache-1';

var resourcesToCache = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
    '/pouchdb.min-6.4.1.js',
    '/styles/inline.css',
    '/scripts/app.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    // open the app browser cache
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
        console.log("Install succesfull");
        // add all app assets to the cache
        return cache.addAll(resourcesToCache);
    }).then(function(out){
        console.log(out);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // try to find corresponding response in the cache
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          // cache hit: return cached result
          return response;
        }

        // not found: fetch resource from the server
        return fetch(event.request);
      }).catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
      })
  );
});
```

And my registration code:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
            console.log('Service worker registered:'+registration.scope);
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    };
```

I didn't get it.. I hope you have an idea :)

EDIT: I think I know now why it don't work. I have a authentication for my domain, so not everybody can access it.
 While my serviceworker want to caching the data, it get 401 back. So it seems to be a problem with the authentication.

Maybe someone had already the same problem?

Comment: Same problem, haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 12):

This happens when your `resourcesToCache` includes something that returns a 404 response. Make sure you have everything typed correctly. Also make sure that the scope is correct. You can check your worker scope using:

```
if("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
  .register(`worker.js`)
  .then(registration => {
    console.log("SW scope:", registration.scope);
  });
}
```

If your project is not in your server domain root, doing something like this might help:

```
//your main js
if("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
  .register(`${window.location.pathname}worker.js`)
  .then(registration => {
    //do your thing
  });
}


//your worker js
let resourcesToCache = [
  './',
  './index.html',
  './jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
  './pouchdb.min-6.4.1.js',
  './styles/inline.css',
  './scripts/app.js',
];
//...
```

As a side-note, you should be loading your libraries (jQuery, pouchdb), from a CDN to improve performance. Those can be cached too:

```
let resourcesToCache = [
  './',
  './index.html',
  'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pouchdb/6.4.3/pouchdb.min.js',
  './styles/inline.css',
  './scripts/app.js',
];
```

Comment: The bit about a 404 response was exactly right for me!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I was developing locally on a windows machine and deploying on a linux server, the problem is with the path. You need to add a '.' before your path for it to be like "./" as follows:

```
var resourcesToCache = [
'./',
'./index.html',
'./jquery-3.2.1.min.js',
'./pouchdb.min-6.4.1.js',
'./styles/inline.css',
'./scripts/app.js'
```

];

Answer (score 1):

This had happened to me when i was referring a file (that don't exist in the path specified) for caching. When i updated the path to the file, things got fine.